# Error while generating pdf with android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm trying to do a pdf creator. I tried a lot and found some coding but i'm still getting an error and i don't know how to solve it. Here is my code:

```
public void GenerarPDF(View view){
try{

  Document document=new Document();
  File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
  if (!root.exists()) {
      root.mkdirs();
  }
  File gpxfile = new File(root, "generando.pdf");
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(gpxfile));
  document.open();
  document.add(new Paragraph("Testing testing and testing"));
  document.close();

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

logcat error says :

```
09-25 07:40:14.337: E/dalvikvm(9397): Could not find class 'org.spongycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder', referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj

09-25 07:40:14.337: W/dalvikvm(9397): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2148 (Lorg/spongycastle/cert/X509CertificateHolder;) in Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader;
```

Please tell what is this error says and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have added itextpdf jar file in libs folder. Incase you have added the library using configure build path, first remove the added jar using same option. Then go to project folder in your workspace and create a libs folder. Then drop the itextpdf jar there. It should solve the problem.Also I've tried the sample code given here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=12. It worked fine for me

Comment: Oh thanks.. and i'm working with emulator right now,I didn't check the destination properly. the same file already created a lot of time. And above mentioned error may be a warning because i'm still getting that error but works fine.